# How do I return a pushed array after awaiting for async .map() to finish?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, axios

The final result is intended to be stored in the `locations` array below.

```
const locations = []
```

I have created an async function that accepts a `location` parameter, which will then be used by `locationSearch` to make a GET request to Google Places.

```
const locationSearch = await (
    axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=${location}`, {json: true})
    .then(response => {
        if(response.data.results.length < 1) throw new Error('Unable to find location.')

        return response.data.results
    }).catch(error => {
        return error
    }) 
)
```

The result returns an array of places which I will then pass on to `locationSearch` to get more details using the `place_id`.

```
const locationDetails = await locationSearch.map(async (locationData) => {
    const { place_id: id } = locationData

    await (
        axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=${id}`, {json: true})
        .then(locationDetails => {
            if(locationDetails.data.result.length === 0) throw new Error('Unable to find location ID!')

            const { name, geometry, types, photos, rating, user_ratings_total, opening_hours, icon, formatted_address, formatted_phone_number, price_level, reviews } = locationDetails.data.result
            locations.push({
                latitude: geometry.location.lat,
                longitude: geometry.location.lng,
                types,
                reviews,
                photos,
                rating,
                user_ratings_total, 
                opening_hours,
                icon,
                name,
                location: formatted_address,
                formatted_phone_number,
                price_level
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            return error
        })
    )
})
```

However, I am not sure where locations should be returned, as `locationDetails` is only used to map the results into `locations`. The resolved Promise is returned as follows:

```
return Promise.all(locationSearch, locationDetails)
```

I hope this question doesn't come across as silly. Additionally, any feedback or pointers on mistakes of the code written will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With async/await, you don't use promise apis like `.then` and `.catch`—it's an alternative to using promise structures. It should look more like this:

```
async function getLocationData (location) {
  try {
    const { data } = axios.get(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=${location}`,
      { json: true }
    )

    if (data.results) {
      const locationDetails = await Promise.all(
        data.results.map(({ place_id }) =>
          // for each of these, catch any errors and return null so you know you got nothing
          // but it won't kill the entire batch of requests
          axios.get(
            `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=${id}`,
            { json: true }
          ).catch(() => null)
        )
      )
      return locationDetails.reduce((arr, details) => {
        // only add the data if it exists
        if (Array.isArray(details.result) && details.result.length) {
          const {
            name,
            geometry,
            types,
            photos,
            rating,
            user_ratings_total,
            opening_hours,
            icon,
            formatted_address,
            formatted_phone_number,
            price_level,
            reviews
          } = details

          return [
            ...arr,
            {
              latitude: geometry.location.lat,
              longitude: geometry.location.lng,
              types,
              reviews,
              photos,
              rating,
              user_ratings_total,
              opening_hours,
              icon,
              name,
              location: formatted_address,
              formatted_phone_number,
              price_level
            }
          ]
        }
        // otherwise it's an errored result (null) or no match
        // so return the accumulated array (essentially a filter)
        return arr
      }, [])
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unable to find location')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}
```

The main thing to be aware of here is that `Promise.all` will stop as soon as any of the requests fail. So you can add a `.catch` to each of the axios calls in the `Promise.all` map to prevent the entire batch from rejecting. Then you'll get an array matching the number of location results and you'll now the failed ones because they'll be `null`, or whatever you want to return for failed requests.

Also, it would be a good idea to be consistent in how you handle errors. Either throw all the time or return all the time.

Comment: Very clear and clean way of solving this, and thank you for pointing out the different approaches!

Comment: glad I could help!